# How to prevent auto rotation like the iPhone photo app does?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uitouch, autorotate

I want to prevent a UICollectionViewController from auto rotation when there's a finger on the screen. The finger could move, the device could rotate, but the UICollectionViewController shouldn't rotate whenever the finger is still on screen.

And the UICollectionViewController should rotate immediately when the finger left the screen. As the iPhone photo app does.

Question:

1. How to detect touch?

   I overwrite the `touchBegan:withEvent:` etc. in UICollectionView subclass. But when the UICollectionView start scrolling, it calls `touchCanceled:withEvent:` method.

   If I start scrolling the UICollectionView earlier, the `touchBegan:withEvent:` does even not fired.
2. How to prevent auto rotation temporarily?

   I overwrite the `shouldAutorotate` in my view controller to prevent rotation. But when the finger left the screen, the UICollectionView can't rotate immediately.

Comment: Du you mean fix Device Orrientation

Comment: I wanna disable rotation temporarily when there's a finger touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
@interface BlockAutorotateViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGestureRecognizer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizer;
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isPressed) BOOL pressed;

@end

@implementation BlockAutorotateViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pressed = NO;

    self.longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myLongPressAction:)];
    self.longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.longPressGestureRecognizer];

    self.swipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mySwipeAction:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.swipeGestureRecognizer];

}

- (void)myLongPressAction:(id)sender
{
    if ((self.longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) || (self.longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged))  {
        self.pressed = YES;
    }
    else if (self.longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        self.pressed = NO;
        [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
    }
    else {
        self.pressed = NO;
    }
}

- (void)mySwipeAction:(id)sender
{
    if ((self.swipeGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) || (self.longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged))  {
        self.pressed = YES;
    }
    else if (self.longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        self.pressed = NO;
        [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
    }
    else {
        self.pressed = NO;
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return (self.isPressed ? NO : YES);
}

@end
```

Comment: @smilingpoplar, which one would you use for this desired feature? Have you tested example above?

Comment: I have tried your code. It doesn't work if I move the finger first, and then rotate the device. In this case, the view shouldn't rotate.

Comment: You have tried without UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged in first if sentence, of course?

Comment: I tried your new code. Your could test like this: quickly tap and swipe on the view, then rotate device.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but you should test this above all, right? :) I'm trying to help you. Also, take some time and study gesture recognisers, it will be easier for you to go further on proposed code. Purpose of this site is not getting free snippets, but collaborate. I'd also advise you to make more clear requests, you will get this many times here. Just a friendly advice.

Comment: Well, I add `self.longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0;`, it seems to work :)

Comment: You see, it's going when collaborate. Yes, minimumPressDuration is a vital one :)

Answer (score 1):

For detecting the touch event, I would recommend using a UIGestureRecognizer rather than overriding the UICollectionViewController's touch events. That way you can be notified of the touch event without interfering with the existing event handling.

You will probably need two custom UIGestureRecognizer classes to implement this, since I don't think UITapGestureRecognizer will meet your needs. You can have one UIGestureRecognizer notify you of finger down events and another notify you when the finger is lifted.

For preventing auto rotation, override shouldAutorotate as you have already done. When your gesture recognizer detects that the finger has been lifted, call [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation] to tell iOS to rotate the UI to the current orientation. (Obviously make sure that shouldAutorotate will now return YES before calling that.)

Comment: Your idea may work. But it needs to implement two custom UIGestureRecognizer. I will try sometime.